# Expressing the probability of a normally distributed RV with μ,σ.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given a random variable $X \stackrel{}{\sim}N(μ,σ^2)$, is it possible to express the probability of $X$ being within $y$ standard deviations of the mean solely with $μ and σ?

EX: What is the probability of $X$ being within 2 deviations of it's mean?

Comment: If $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with $\sigma^2 \neq 0,$ the probability that $X$ is within $2$ standard deviations of its mean is approximately $0.9545,$ regardless of the particular values of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2.$ It's not clear what kind of "in terms of" you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $k$ the number of standard deviations that you are interested in, where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, thus the probability of being within $k$ standard deviations from the mean $\mu$ is
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(|X - \mu|\le k\sigma ) &= \mathbb{P}(\mu - k\sigma\le X \le \mu + k\sigma )\\
                                  &= \Phi\left( \frac{k\sigma}{\sigma} \right) - \Phi\left( - \frac{ k\sigma}{\sigma} \right) \\
& = 2\Phi\left( k \right) -1. 
\end{align}

Comment: Nice (+1) For $k = 1,2,3,$ values are  0.6826895, 0.9544997, 0.9973002. Notice the similarity of these numbers to those in the so-called Empirical Rule, which works reasonably well for nearly-normal data.

Comment: What is the Phi function in this case?

Comment: Cumulative distribution function of the normal standard variable, i.e., $\Phi(k) = \int_{\infty}^k 1/\sqrt{ 2\pi } \exp\{-z^2/2\}dz$

Comment: This works for non-standard normal distributions even though it uses the SND CDF?

Comment: Sure. I've started from just a normal (non standard) r.v.

Comment: In your comment, shouldn't the integral be from -infinity to k?

Comment: Sure. I've noticed it too late so I couldn't edit it

Answer (score 0):

For $a>0$:

$P(|x-\mu|<a\ \sigma) = {\rm Erf}[a/\sqrt{2}]$